# L2S, Caching, and error: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a fairly complex query (that includes a table valued function to allow full text searching) that I am trying to cache (HttpRuntime.Cache) for paging purposes. When I try to use the cached L2S query, I get the error stated above: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.

I have tried assigning my query to another IQueryable object by calling AsIQueryable() on the cached object, but that does not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the results of the query in the cache instead of the query itself by calling [`.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) or [`.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension methods which will execute the query immediately. Then you can enumerate the results from the cache as much as you wish.

Comment: Thanks Darin - seems pretty obvious, but in the midst of other L2S issues, and using unfamiliar technology to begin with (asp.net mvc) I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

use

var retVal = (.....).First() or ToList();

and use retVal.Name, retVal.Surname ....

if you use ToList();, you need to give an index like retVal[1].Name